# Read static files with express got "Cannot Get /"

Tags: html, node.js, express, socket.io

I tried to learn how to read static files with express from a reliable website. And then I found that not know why, my terminal tell me I'm success but website show me `"Cannot Get /"`(as following image show). I had found a lot of solution (e.g. in my `html` file, I add script src to `socket.io`) but still fail. Where can I start to deal with it? Please help me...

[terminal show success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTWsZ.png)

[website show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FhAA.png)

And the following is my code:

C:\...\1-on-1-webrtc\server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)

// static data
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))

// TODO: Signaling

//start server listen 8080 port
http.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`Server running in 8080`)
})
```

C:\...\1-on-1-webrtc\pubilc\index.html

(origin)

```
"hello"
```

(after)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>111</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>"hello"</h1>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo. The directory name `pubilc` and the directory name you pass  to `static` `'/public/'` need to match.

Comment: Is it means that I should change `(__dirname + '/public/'))` to `(__dirname + '/public/index.html'))` , or I misunderstand?

Comment: You change should `(__dirname + '/public/'))` to `(__dirname + '/pubilc/'))` because that is what you said the directory was named. (Or rename the directory which would make the spelling better overall)

Comment: @Sojona108 You have typo in name of your Public folder ! ;-) Change the name of your "pubilc" to "public"

Comment: @Quentin: Oh my godness!!! Thank you, it works!!! It's all my fault, I didn't even notice I spelled it wrong! Actually, I look for why it not works for about 3 days... What have I done?

Comment: @Sojona108 Did the answer solve your question ?

Comment: @MarioG8: Yes, I had succeeded, thank you!

Comment: @Sojona108 So You Can marked it as it solved your problem ;-) Thx !

Comment: @MarioG8: I'm so sorry, let's me find where to mark it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change Your code a little and here is my solution:

Firstly change your name of `public` folder to correct. Not "pubilc" only "public".

**Folder & File** Structure:

[image]

**server.js** :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
// const http = require("http").createServer(app);

// static data
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

//start server listen 8080 port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is  listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**index.html** (without any changes) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>111</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>"hello"</h1>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output** :

[image]

*Tested with: express 4.17.2 node 16.13.0 Linux Ubuntu 20.04 and Win10*

Comment: I tried your way but still get "Cannot GET /" and "Cannot GET /index.html". With express 4.16.1 node 16.13.2 on Windows. (My folder and file structure is as same as yours.) Is it possible that it only works on ubuntu? Because the website I'm looking for is also processed by ubuntu. Or unrelate with the operating system...?

Comment: @Sojona108 It also works on windows! Now I was checking. Just copy my code install express and run in node server.js project folder then click on localhost: 8080 link in console and done. There is no way it won't work ... ;-) Slowly, no nerves ...

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. You should explain what you changed and **why** it should solve the problem. Looking at it, You don't seem to have done anything at all to make the HTML document load.

Comment: @Quentin Thx for your valuable advice. I apologies for my mistakes  ;-)

Comment: @MarioG8: It still can't work. Maybe I miss something I don't know. Perhaps I should cool down and retry it with a new fold. Thanks for your answer, and if I success I will reply to you~

Comment: @Sojona108 You are welcome ! Try to create new project with correct folder and file structure and rest is in my answer to You ;-) Best regards !

Comment: Thanks for you two!! My godness... So shy on it.

Comment: @Quentin: In fact, I tried the processing methods of other websites yesterday, and the reading was successful, so I came back to test today but did not expect that it would still fail. Sorry, I should tell how I dealt with it before.